# Magento 2 checkout, I need to display or hide a shipping method depending on if a coupon code was entered and is valid. How can I do this?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, plugin, coupon-codes, mixins

I have a price rule attached to the flat rate shipping method as an option, and I want to intercept when the coupon is added, so that I can hide this flat rate method unless the coupon code matches the code value in the option. I have a model setup for retrieving the coupon code that is attached to the shipping method, but I don't know how to hide, show and auto select a shipping method once I compare the coupon codes.

For example, I am not sure if it is possible to do what I want when I override `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost`.

[image]

Comment: As I understand , you want a coupon code which will hide flat rate shipping, and free shipping will get enabled? Please share some snapshots to clear your view.

Comment: Actually I edited it. I meant flat rate that is set to $5.

Comment: got that, now you want to show this flat rate shipping when a desired coupon code matches, else it will remain hidden, right.

Comment: As of right now it is enabled and showing. But I can adjust to whatever works. But yes, I believe you have the right idea.

Comment: I want to apply the flat rate shipping only when the coupon code is provided, else, I want it to not be shown.